# Is it possible to space components in the same row? [React Native Design]

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to space out these two components (heart and flag) while keeping them in the same row. I have rounded the cell and added a bottom border to give you an idea of where the icons lie relative to the screen. As you can see, they are right in the middle:

[image]

I would like the heart and the number of likes to be on the far left, with the flag on the far right. I am having trouble spacing them without hardcoding the width I would like them to be. Here is the code:

```
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'left', alignItems: 'center'}}>

                <LikeComponent postID = {this.state.postID} />

                <ReportComponent postID = {this.state.postID} />
                
            </View>
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>

  <LikeComponent postID = {this.state.postID} />

  <ReportComponent postID = {this.state.postID} />
            
</View>
```

Use

> justifyContent: 'space-between'

, If you also want to space on the right and left margin of the screen then use,

> justifyContent: space-around

Comment: Neither of these worked unfortunately. I tried with and without the flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', and justifyContent: 'space-around'

Comment: Ahh, never mind, this works perfectly! I had the view wrapped in a container that had alignItems: center, so that messed things up. flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' is the right solution